# Initializing an array of class with certain number of elements in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am looking for a way to initialize an array of type `Passenger` which its number of elements is equal to the value of variable `count`. How can I do it in `ngOnInit()`???

This is the `Passenger` model:

```
export class Passenger {
    constructor(
        public ageCategory: string = '',
        public name: string = '',
        public lastName: string = '',
        public Ssn: string = '',
        public birtDate: NgbDate = new NgbDate(0, 0, 0),
        public passportDate: NgbDate = new NgbDate(0, 0, 0),
        public gender: string = '',
        public passportCountry: string = ''
    ) { }
}
```

And this the content of `home.component.ts`:

```
import { Passenger } from '../../models/passenger';


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  passengers: Passenger[];
  count: number = 5;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.passengers = new Array<Passenger>(3);
}
```

To add empty Passenger objects:

```
passengers: Passenger[] = [];

ngOnInit(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.count;i++){
        let pass= new Passenger();
        this.passengers.push(pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this way. But It does not call the constructor of ```Passenger```.

Comment: So you need to add Passenger objects into the array. You can do like ebove

Answer (score 1):

Call the constructor from within a map:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.passengers = new Array(this.count)
    .fill(0)
    .map(_ => new Passenger());
}
```

Comment: this won't work.`new Array` will generate a array with empty slots and they will be ignored in `map`

Comment: @Austaras I did not know that. Thanks! Updated my answer for what it's worth.